# Not finding javascript function

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this error saying that it cannot find my javascript function checkpw(). It's being called by onfocus.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

function checkpw() { 

alert ("working");

}



</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Welcome to our webpage.</h2>

<p>{{ reginfo}}</p>
<form action="/validate/" method ="get" >
<p>Username</p>
<input type="text" name="username"  class="textbox"> </input > </br>
<p>Password</p>
<input class="textbox" name="password" id="password" type="text"> </input > </br>
<p>Confirm Password</p>
<input class="textbox" id="checkpw" type="text" onfocus="checkpw()"> </input > </br>
<p>Email<p>
<input class="textbox" name="email" type="text"> </input > </br>

<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"> 



</form>

</body>
```

I'm probably making a really stupid mistake but i'm new to javascript so anything that helps would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*change*: `function checkpw()` *to*: `function checkPw()`
*and*: `focus="checkpw()"` *to*: `focus="checkPw()"`

---

***Edit:***
It is **not** a reserved word; however the name is already polluted in the global namespace.  As [Domenic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3191/domenic) and [jimr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121006/jimr) pointed out, the `id` attribute is using the same name, thus causing a conflicting condition.

*The solution is still to change either:
(1) the `id` value of the input element
-or-
(2) the function name (as I stated above)*

Comment: It is not a reserved word or function.

Comment: You're right it's not.  But I did find something weird happening on jsFiddle with `checkpw`, changing it fixed it, but then I did some other testing and it did not work.  Mind you, I'm testing in Safari at the moment.

Comment: The reason for the behavior is explained by @jimr's answer, which is correct and should be the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks Domenic, yes you both are right.  I had the fix w/o the right reasoning

Answer (score 3):

Due to behavior that some ancient version of Internet Explorer implemented, in "quirks" mode, most browsers will let you directly address an element by its id.

E.g.

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
  test.innerHTML = 'Hi';
</script>
```

I think this is what's happening for you.  You have an element with id `checkpw` and also a function named `checkpw`.  I think as the element is defined later on in the file, it is winning out, and since it's not a function, attempting to invoke it in your `onfocus` handler doesn't work.

Either change the name of your function, change the `id` of the element, or (more preferably) ensure that your page is not rendering in "quirks" mode (e.g. proper doctype, no invalid HTML, etc)